# Preciso colocar um elemento na direita enquanto o restante fica na esquerda. CSS

Tags: css

Preciso deixar a Palavra Tabela no canto Direito bem afastada la na ponta, enquanto as outras 3 palavras ficam proximas entre si na esquerda, eu cheguei perto quando usei o space-between/space-aroud, mas as palavras estavam distante.

```html
<section class="tabelas">
        <div>
           <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Premier League</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">La Liga</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Campeonato Brasileiro</a></li>
            <li><a class="direita">Tabela</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
```

css

```css
.tabelas  {
  background: #CC59D2;
  
}
```

.tabelas  li, a, ul {
text-decoration: none;

font-weight: bold;
color: black;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
padding: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
}
.direita {
color: white;
display: flex;
align-self: flex-end;
}

Answer (score -3):

Oi, n sei se vai ficar simples fazer um responsivo disso (n sei a ideia do seu projeto mas espero q dê tudo certo ^^). Aqui deu certo assim:

HTML:

```
<li class="direita"><a>Tabela</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
.direita {
  text-align: right;
}
```

(coloquei o `class="direita"` na `li`.